# Cakephp can't find my model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

So, I have two cake apps(one is the site front-end, another is my admin dashboard), all my models are being declared on my admin app, so I load them on my website app:

```
App::build(
    array('Model' => array(
        Configure::read('Extranet.path') . 'app/Model')
    ), App::RESET);
```

This seem to be working fine, since when I do:

```
var_dump(App::objects('Model'), false);
```

I get:

```
array(19) { [0]=> string(8) "AppModel" [1]=> string(6) "Banner" [2]=> string(5) "Brand" [3]=> string(8) "Category" [4]=> string(12) "CategorySize" [5]=> string(5) "Color" [6]=> string(8) "Customer" [7]=> string(11) "EntityImage" [8]=> string(6) "Gender" [9]=> string(5) "Group" [10]=> string(5) "Image" [11]=> string(10) "Newsletter" [12]=> string(10) "Permission" [13]=> string(7) "Product" [14]=> string(12) "ProductImage" [15]=> string(4) "Size" [16]=> string(6) "Status" [17]=> string(11) "UsageStatus" [18]=> string(4) "User" } bool(false)
```

Looks like cake is recognizing my models, however when I try to call an specific method:

```
<?php
class PagesController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Permission');
    public $uses = array('User');

    public function index() {
        var_dump(App::objects('Model'), false);
        $this->User->test();
        $this->set('page', 'home');
    }
}
```

All I get is:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test' at line 1
```

According to my searchs, when the cake tries to perform a SQL query exactly like the method name, it's because it's not finding the model class(but it finds it when dumping App::objects!).

I didn't find any place on how I should go to find out why can't cakephp load my model(and it bothers me even more to know that cake hides this from me instead of screaming at my face).

How should I proceed?

---

Edit:
This is the piece of text from cakephp docs:

> CakePHP will dynamically create a model object for you if it cannot find a corresponding file in /app/Model. This also means that if your model file isn’t named correctly (for instance, if it is named ingredient.php or Ingredients.php rather than Ingredient.php), CakePHP will use an instance of AppModel rather than your model file (which CakePHP assumes is missing). If you’re trying to use a method you’ve defined in your model, or a behavior attached to your model, and you’re getting SQL errors that are the name of the method you’re calling, it’s a sure sign that CakePHP can’t find your model and you need to check the file names, your application cache, or both.

However, my file is correctly named `User.php`, my cache folder is completely empty and I have `Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);` on my bootstrap.php.

Any direction to finding out at least which file is cake php trying to load would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a test() method in your User model??

Comment: Yes, I do(and I can use it just fine on my admin dashboard app)

Answer (score 0):

Three hours and a bunch of var_dumps later, I've found the error and, as odd as it sounds, it was just a matter of changing

```
Configure::read('Extranet.path') . 'app/Model')
```

to

```
Configure::read('Extranet.path') . 'app/Model/')
```

That's what you get from blindly copying with no reading, when the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#adding-paths-for-app-to-find-packages-in) clearly states:

```
All paths must be terminated with a directory separator.
```

Cakephp could be nicer though instead of simply going along without telling me about what's happening.